# Hive - Output to CSV File

Tags: unix, hive

I'd like a process to export a file into a comma separated file from a hive table. Some of the columns may themselves include commas, so not sure how to correct for that. All the commands I've tried on the internet thus far will export the files but does not put them in csv format correctly.

Anyone have a command already figured out?

Comment: use a delimiter that's not in the data? The <tab> char is very difficult for an end user to enter into a an onscreen form. (not impossible) and I don't know the nature of data. But that would be simpliest. Good luck.

Comment: Was hoping... maybe something along the lines of quote enclosed... or something.

Comment: embedded commas in comma delimited data is a well known bug-a-boo in unix/linux programming. You have to bend over backwards to accomplish this with unix/linux tools because it is assumed that the field delimiter will be unique. There was a csv extractor code posted to `comp.unix.awk` years ago that allegedly could deal with your case (and was functionalized). so it my pay spend searching on your terms at .https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/comp.lang.awk . ....

Comment: Unfortunately, the word is even google groups wasn't able to tame the quagmire of net-news groups and that many articles are now lost from the normally available archives. I'll be happy for you or someone else to correct my belief on this ;-) ... Good luck.

Comment: There was also a csv parser tool that an individual developer made available and he plugged several times in comp.lang.awk. But I don't remember the developer's name, his tool's name or anything except that several people replied with deep gratitude, that it had saved their jobs etc. Good luck

Comment: And ... finally, you'll want to learn to search here on stackoverflow with some simple search terms because many Qs have been asked many, many times. Oh look what I found searching with `[awk] csv parsting` ... : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578119/awk-recursive-descent-csv-parser?s=1|3.5181 (among 230 others). Good luck.